# Python: 4 for cycles, comparing list items

Tags: python, cycle

I have a quite scary algorithm to compare distances between atoms, however it works not the i want it to work. Here is the code:

```
for k in ResListA:
  for n in ResListB:
    for m in ResListA[counter3].atoms:
        for z in ResListB[counter4].atoms:
            coordDist = distance.distance(ResListA[counter3].atoms[counter4],ResListB[counter2].atoms[counter1])
            counter1 = counter1 + 1
        counter1 = 0         
        counter4 = counter4 + 1 
    counter4 = 0
    counter2 = counter2 + 1
  counter2 = 0
  counter3 = counter3 + 1
```

Basically i want that minimal distance between

> ResListA[0].atoms[0,..,n]
>
> ResListB[0,..,k].atoms[0,..,m]

to be calculated. However, it calculates

> ResListA[0].atoms[0]

to

> ResListB[0,..,k].atoms[0,..,m]

For example:

> ResListA[N,P,C,N,C] ResListB[C,C][P,P]...

It should be

> dist(N,C) dist(N,C) dist(P,C) dist(P,C)

not

> dist(N,C) dist(N,C) dist(N,P) dist (N,P)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It is quite scary, and the indentation doesn't seem quite right.

Comment: You appear to be using `counter1` before it has been assigned anything.

Comment: If you can stand to take on a Numpy/Scipy dependency, this really looks like a job for [`scipy.spatial.cdist`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html), since you're doing pairwise distances.

Comment: i would love to take libs and plugins and bunch of useful stuff, but i have an assignment, to make it myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your code can be written more like this.

```
for k in ResListA:
    for n in ResListB:
        for m in k.atoms:
            for z in n.atoms:
                coordDist = distance.distance(m.atoms, z.atoms)
```

no idea what `distance.distance` does. Shouldn't you be doing something with `coordDist` involving `min()`?

Comment: I think you mean `distance.distance(m, z)`.

Comment: distance is a module, which i use for a simple 3D distance calculation. Overall i am trying to get a matrix with minimal distances between amino acids, which contains atoms, of which i want count the distance.

Comment: @gnibbler, tested your code, it gives the same outcome, it still goes through all of `ResListB` with with the first atom from `ResListA`

Answer (score 0):

While gnibbler is probably correct in that is what you should do, this is what your current code simplifies to:

```
for k in ResListA:
    for n in ResListB:
        for counter4, m in enumerate(k.atoms):
            for counter1, z in enumerate(ResListB[counter4].atoms):
                coordDist = distance.distance(m, n.atoms[counter1])
```

Your problem is that you need:

```
for z in ResListB[counter2].atoms:
```

instead of

```
for z in ResListB[counter4].atoms:
```